# If Condition Integer

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to understand how this algorithm works. I have a class Permute with a method permute() which prints all possible permutations of a given array. I tried with `{1, 2, 3}`. When I checked with the debugger, I didn't understand how this if-statement works `if (k == arr.size() -1)`
It evaluates to false when `k == 1` and `arr.size() == 3`, and evaluates to true when `k == 2 and arr.size() == 3`.

```
public class Permute
{
    static void permute(java.util.List<Integer> arr, int k){
        for(int i = k; i < arr.size(); i++){
            java.util.Collections.swap(arr, i, k);
            permute(arr, k+1);
            java.util.Collections.swap(arr, k, i);
        }
        if (k == arr.size() -1){
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr.toArray()));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Permute.permute(java.util.Arrays.asList(1,2,3), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: For `arr.size()` = 3, then  `arr.size() - 1` = 2 which = k = 2.

Answer (score 1):

arr.size()-1 == 2 when the size is 3. So it's a match.

arr.size()-1 == 1 when the size is 2, so it doesn't match 1;

the check is using the -1 bit because array indexes start at 0. So an array with 5 elements will go 0,1,2,3,4  and the size will equal 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking why if (k == arr.size() -1) returned true or false from the given inputs -

*evaluates to false when k == 1 and arr.size() == 3*

Here if checks is `1 == (3-1)?`. It isn't equal so returns false.

*and evaluates to true when k == 2 and arr.size() == 3.*

Here if checks is `2 == (3-1)?` It is equal and so returns true.